# Intellij Idea 2017.1.X can't read plugin.xml of maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am trying to integrate a new plugin into my project, namely spring-mvc-raml plugin. It works like a charm, but my Idea can't read plugin.xml from META-INF/maven obviously:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.phoenixnap.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>springmvc-raml-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${springmvc-raml-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <ramlPath>src/main/resources/api.raml</ramlPath>
                <outputRelativePath>target/generated-sources</outputRelativePath>
                <addTimestampFolder>false</addTimestampFolder>
                <basePackage>com.thomascook.digital.booking.amendment.web</basePackage>
                <baseUri>/api</baseUri>
                <seperateMethodsByContentType>false</seperateMethodsByContentType>
                <rule>com.phoenixnap.oss.ramlapisync.generation.rules.Spring4ControllerInterfaceRule</rule>
                <generationConfig>
                    <includeHashcodeAndEquals>false</includeHashcodeAndEquals>
                    <includeToString>false</includeToString>
                    <includeJsr303Annotations>true</includeJsr303Annotations>
                </generationConfig>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-springmvc-endpoints</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-springmvc-endpoints</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Idea highlights all tags inside `<configuration>`

What's interesting, it doesn't complain for other guys who started working on it a while ago. I tried it on both Windows and Ubuntu, using Idea 2017.1.4 and 2017.1.3.

Any thought? Cache invalidation didn't help me either.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried Idea 2017.2.5 and with it everything is fine. Now I'm curious what have changed in the way Idea parse plugin.xml in 2017.2.X? Anyone from Intellij?